# slide-in uitoolbar

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode

I would like to add a uitoolbar able to slide -in from the top of the screen when some button is pushed. With all the research done this week-end I am still stuck. Please help.

Comment: UINavigationBar has this functionality built in. If you don't want to use one of those, do you know how to do basic animations on UIViews? It would help if you divulged a bit more info about the research you've done, so we can give you a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a UIToolbar within a UINavigationController you may simply call:

```
- (void)setNavigationBarHidden:(BOOL)hidden animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Otherwise you'll have to setup a [custom animation](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/user-interface/sliding-views-on-and-off-screen-creating-a-reusable-sliding-message-widget.html).